# Issue on qz.jZebra multi pages print

Tags: javascript, printing, applet, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I am using jZerba print plugin for our POS invoice print, I created a ftl and send that to jZebra HTML print, everything has worked as expected, but when the it comes to multiple pages it prints only first page, other pages got trimmed, I had tried a lot but none of them helped me, please help me in this issue.

I have used setEndOfDocument, setDocumentsPerSpool but it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long conversation with jZebra community, for printHtml there is no support for multi pages print, After I looked for jZebra HTML5 print it also makes issues, its works for multi pages print, but if invoice is for a small bill, it stretches the text and looks ugly, finally I convert my HTML to Pdf using flying saucer and send that path to print, it works good, but as I checked with the plugin they again convert the pdf to inputstream, so it double the process. Currently I think there is no possible ways to send bytes to jZebra, if there is any options please lemme know.